How to set ut jira projects for multiple project managers and multiple teams with different workflows
I work at a relatively small tech company. We have a cloud team, an embedded/electronics team, and a PLC team. We do projects towards several customers which are regarded as separate projects.
I try to puzzle out how to best create a jira environment which works for everyone.
So far I see it like this.
Create a new jira project for each customer project. This is where the project manager lives. Work a lot with epics etc to get the overview of the project. It can contain both tasks for embedded team and cloud team, or perhaps plc team. This would be great for the project manager so that he can get a limited view of his work.
Then create 3 separate jira projects for developers: cloud, embedded and PLC. Create the specific tasks for customer projects here but make sure to link all work to epics in jira customer projects.
Is there another way of doing it?
I thought of only creating projects for cloud, embedded and PLC and then use labels to link to a customer project. But that would then make it harder for the PMs to keep the project together in one place. Where to put the epics that span over the teams/disciplines?
TLDR: What I want is:

Project managers can see and plan his project in 1 space
Developer teams can see their work in 1 place (the board containing tasks from several projects)
Teams can have their own workflows
Prepare for expansion (more teams in the future).

Is there a "best practice" regarding this?
All tips are welcome
So I am responsible for setting up the task management system and I chose Jira since I have some experience with it from previous dev jobs.
My first move was to set up the environment for the cloud team since they are the largest group of people. Set up several different projects and called them "Customer x cloud", "customer y cloud" etc. Then had a "Planning project" that hosted the board and filtered on all the different projects. So the teams can have their board and see which tasks are most prioritized etc.
But now Embedded and PLC also needs to enter the stage. I dont want to create another set of projects named "Customer x PLC", "Customer X embedded" cause alot of work and alot of projects. But I also don't want to simply create "Embedded" project and "PLC" project because I believe that the project managers won't be able to find/manage their work/sprints together with other PMs.
Another option would be to use "Plans" but I don't find it very intuitive working with multiple projects to be fair.
Any input is greatly appreciated.

Your question is not about programming or developing for Jira, only a general question on how to use the product.

You may find you get better responses to your question on project management stack exchange https://pm.stackexchange.com/

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I would recommend you use projects in Jira to represent projects in the real world. This will give the project manager and other stakeholders in the organisation a view on progress of the projects.
Then, use labels and quick filters to give specialist teams a view that only shows work relevant to them. This will give the individual teams the view they need to progress their backlog.

Yes this could be acceptable. However, for cloud we want to use workflow such as "ready for review", "Stage testing" etc. This is not applicable for embedded team. To my knowledge, it is not possible to have different workflows inside one project?

Yes. It is possible by creating different issue types and assigning them different workflows. So, you will have different issue types for the work of the different teams. This will work.
